# Checkbox issue: Checked="checked" not working

Tags: html, checkbox, mustache, handlebars.js

I am having a weird problem with checkboxes; in this piece of code:

```
<div class="two-column-layout">
    <input type="checkbox" name="externalSystemEndPoint" class="hidden" />
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="endPoint-{{endPointCode}}" name="externalSystemEndPoint" title="{{externalSystemName}}" value="{{endPointCode}}" {{disabledAttribute mandatory}}/>
    <label for="endPoint-{{endPointCode}}" class="checkbox-label">{{externalSystemName}}</label>
</div>
```

Even the second checkbox (with `id="endPoint-{{endPointCode}}"`) it's appearing, the effect of the attribute `checked="checked"` is not being applied.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
This is the HTML code generated:

```
<fieldset class="form-fieldset ui-corner-all">
    <legend class="form-fieldset-legend ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
        External Systems
    </legend>

    <div class="two-column-layout">
        <input type="checkbox" name="externalSystemEndPoint" class="hidden">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="endPoint-CHIX_ENDPOINT" name="externalSystemEndPoint" title="Childrens Index" value="CHIX_ENDPOINT">
        <label for="endPoint-CHIX_ENDPOINT" class="checkbox-label">Childrens Index</label>
    </div>

    <div class="two-column-layout">
        <input type="checkbox" name="externalSystemEndPoint" class="hidden">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="endPoint-CIIX_ENDPOINT" name="externalSystemEndPoint" title="Citizens Index" value="CIIX_ENDPOINT">
        <label for="endPoint-CIIX_ENDPOINT" class="checkbox-label">Citizens Index</label>
    </div>          
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML code look like?

Comment: Are you using Angualr for the templates? What is value of {{disabledAttribute mandatory}} ? Please provide the JavaScript for this as well.

Comment: @Guffa I've just updated the question with the generated HTML

Comment: @AdityaSingh It's basically a simple checker, but believe me, I think it's not related with the issue.

Comment: Your posted HTML seems to be working, in [a JS Fiddle reproduction](http://jsfiddle.net/gu8tnhfd/).

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for the JS Fiddle man, this making it even more weird

Comment: Do you have any script that might change the checked status after the element is created?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine in the below snippet. Maybe some issue with your template. Let me know the details of the scenario if you still face the issue

```css
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="form-fieldset ui-corner-all">
    <legend class="form-fieldset-legend ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
        External Systems
    </legend>

    <div class="two-column-layout">
        <input type="checkbox" name="externalSystemEndPoint" class="hidden">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="endPoint-CHIX_ENDPOINT" name="externalSystemEndPoint" title="Childrens Index" value="CHIX_ENDPOINT">
        <label for="endPoint-CHIX_ENDPOINT" class="checkbox-label">Childrens Index</label>
    </div>

    <div class="two-column-layout">
        <input type="checkbox" name="externalSystemEndPoint" class="hidden">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="endPoint-CIIX_ENDPOINT" name="externalSystemEndPoint" title="Citizens Index" value="CIIX_ENDPOINT">
        <label for="endPoint-CIIX_ENDPOINT" class="checkbox-label">Citizens Index</label>
    </div>          
</fieldset>
```